# Expecting member declaration with kotlin

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

First, I'm sorry to use a translator because I can't speak English.

I tried to implement app server communication through retrofit.

But I got this error for the next code.

```
service.getinfo()?.enqueue(object : Callback<student> {//22

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<student>, response: Response<student>) {
        if(response.isSuccessful){
            var result: student? = response.body()
            Log.d("YMC", "onResponse 성공: " result?.toString())//27
        }else{
            // 통신이 실패한 경우(응답코드 3xx, 4xx 등)
            Log.d("YMC", "onResponse 실패")
        }

    }
Expecting member declaration :22
Expecting member declaration :22
Expecting member declaration :22
Name expected :22
Unresolved reference: result :27
Expecting an element :27
Expecting an expression :27
Property "service" is never used :20
Variable 'result' is never used :26
```

I couldn't figure out exactly what the problem was because I wrote the example code without the variable name to learn the basic usage of retrofit.

This is my main activity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("myserverURL")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
val service = retrofit.create(StudentService::class.java)

service.getinfo()?.enqueue(object : Callback<student> {

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<student>, response: Response<student>) {
        if(response.isSuccessful){
            var result: student? = response.body()
            Log.d("YMC", "onResponse 성공: " result?.toString())
        }else{
            // 통신이 실패한 경우(응답코드 3xx, 4xx 등)
            Log.d("YMC", "onResponse 실패")
        }

    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<student>, t: Throwable) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
 }
}
```

This is the content of the student data class.

```
data class student(
@SerializedName("id") val id:Int,
@SerializedName("hashedPW") val hashedPW:Char,
@SerializedName("hp") val hp:Char,
@SerializedName("name") val name:Char
)
```

This is an interface to communicate with the server

```
interface StudentService {
@GET("info/studentList")
fun getinfo(): Call<student>
}
```

Comment: At least one issue is here: `Log.d("YMC", "onResponse 성공: " result?.toString())`. Looks like you meant to do string concatenation, but you forgot the `+` (though using string interpolation would be more idiomatic Kotlin). Also, are you sure those properties of `student` (first letter should be uppercase, by the way, to match standard naming conventions) should be `Char` and not something like `String`? I doubt a student's name or "hashed password" would be a single character long.

Comment: You might also be missing a closing `}` for the `object : Callback<student>`, though it's hard to tell with the formatting of your question.

Comment: You're missing a `)` (to close `enqueue(...)`). `service.getInfo()...` needs to be inside a function, e.g. ``onCreate`` (you've closed `onCreate` after the `setContentView` line)